# glGenVertexArrays() crashing DerelictGL3 program

Tags: d, opengl-3, vertex-array-object, derelict3

The function calls `glBindVertexArray(0)`, `glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object)` and `glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object)` cause my program to crash. When I run the code `if(glGenVertexArrays == null)` it evaluates true. This leads me to believe I'm not loading the functions properly. I'm using `DerelictGL3.load()` and `DerelictGL3.reload()` to load my functions but I'm not sure it's working. Other functions do seem to load though, only functions pertaining to the vertex array object crash the program.

Edit: 
I'm not sure what the actual problem is but it seems to be related to the way Mac OSX loads OpenGL functions. My code does not crash on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `DerelictGL3.reload()` be sure to have an active OpenGL context created (through SDL or SFML or whatever other technique you use).
Else you'll get function pointers only for a minimal OpenGL subset, something like OpenGL 1.1.

Comment: I believe I am. I create my OpenGL context with SDL in a class Display. A display class is initialized before the mesh class. If I remove the vertex array function calls, the context window does not crash.